# Fixed sidebar causing trouble to bootstrap responsive design

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using a fixed sidebar for my page and I am using bootstrap to make it responsive design. However, when I try different screen resolution, my content is going out of the screen rather than going down to the first div. Please see the screenshot for the more easy explanation.

I tried everything possible still nothing worked. Attached is screenshot for problem, and my code.

**Expected Output:** (1440px works fine)

[image]

**Error :** (1024px does not work)

[image]

**Works :** (954px works)
[image]

**HTML :**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <header>
        <div class="header_wrapper"></div>
    </header>


    <div class="sidebar">

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div style="height: 70px;background: #5bd495;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <section>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="container" style="padding-top:50px;">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <div class="form_container" style="height:600px;background:#d69c9c; border:2px solid #000000;"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <div class="form_container" style="height:600px;background:#96e09e;border:2px solid #000000;"></div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

</body>

</html>
```

**CSS :**

```
 html, body {
    overflow-x : hidden;
}

.header_wrapper {
    height: 70px;
    background: #fff;
}

.sidebar {
    background-color: #fff;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 180px;
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    filter: drop-shadow(-5px 0px 10px #B0DFC0);
}

.wrapper {
    background: #F1FAF4;
    padding-left: 200px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}

.form_container {
    background: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 20px 30px;
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 5px 15px #B0DFC0);
    margin-bottom: 70px;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to add the ```col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-7``` with ```col-md-7``` same goes for ```col-md-5```

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, that did not work.Still getting the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed div container with div wrapper and that did it.
https://jsfiddle.net/jee7384b/13/

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">         </script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="header_wrapper"></div>
    </header>
    <div class="sidebar">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div style="height: 70px;background: #5bd495;"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <section>
      <div class="container" style="padding-top:50px;">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-7">
              <div class="form_container" style="height:600px;background:#d69c9c; border:2px solid #000000;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
              <div class="form_container" style="height:600px;background:#96e09e;border:2px solid #000000;"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Also, you should style everything in the css file.

Comment: wow ! that worked like a charm! However, I did not get the concept how does that make any difference? About putting style in CSS, this is just snippet of my code. ! Thanks for the help!

Comment: One more thing I noticed is content container background color is not spread over the whole background!